# good SBC for Blender-CLI 3d rendering

Tags: raspberry-pi, sbc, rendering

I have approx. $250, and I need something like a Single Board Computer to process my blender renders. My machine doesn't support cuda or vulkan, so it has to render via cpu and it is tediously slow.

My first guess was something like the raspberry pi 5, but then searching I came across other SBCs like OrangePi 5 plus (16GB), RockPi 5 (8gb) and even Nvidia jetson nano series of boards. I am new to the world of single board computers (I don't even know if it is the right place for my question). I want to know which board should I for $250 for 3D rendering. I am lost, I don't know which parameters in the specs I should consider or which brand or board I should get and even if there are better options not listed above that I don't know.

Please give me some information about this beautiful, but yet new world for me.

Comment: Hi Dario, welcome to Hardware Recs. Is there a reason you can't just buy a GPU and install it in your machine?

Comment: Yes, I have a laptop, more precisely a Huawei matebook d15 with 8gb of ram and an i51135g7 and I have to process render through CPU, because the IGpu isn't recognized

Comment: In general I have $250 dollars to improve my render times, and due to the fact that I have a laptop I can't upgrade it, so I thought about a SBC, but I don't know if it is the best choice. My goal Is only to improve render times, not using an SBC at all costs

Comment: I think your best option would be trying to find an extremely cheap used PC locally for about $50 (such as an Optiplex 790), and then spend the spend the remaining $200 or so on an RTX 2060 and a power supply upgrade, if required.